# show 'no solution found' when array length is 0

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I want to have three stages in my component.

1. Data is loading => show loading state
2. When data is fetched => show data
3. When data is fetched but it's an empty array => show 'no solution found'

I have implemented the first two but having a problem implementing the third one.
Right now, it's showing loading animation when the length of the array is 0 but I want to show 'no solution found' when there is no data present in the DB.

Github Repo: https://github.com/rishipurwar1/coding-space

src/components/smallComponents/Tabs.js Component Code:

```
import React, { useState } from "react"
import useFirestore from "../../hooks/useFirestore"
import ChallengeCard from "../challenges/ChallengeCard"
import SolutionSummary from "../solutions/SolutionSummary"
import SkeletonCard from "../skeletons/SkeletonCard"

const Tabs = ({ userID }) => {
  const [openTab, setOpenTab] = useState(1)
  const { docs = [] } = useFirestore("solutions", null, userID, openTab)
  return (
    <>
      <div className="flex flex-wrap">
        <div className="w-full">
          <ul className="flex mb-0 list-none flex-wrap pt-3 pb-4 flex-row" role="tablist">
            <li className="-mb-px xs:mb-4 sm:mr-2 last:mr-0 flex-auto text-center">
              <a
                className={
                  "text-xs font-bold uppercase px-5 py-3 shadow-lg rounded block leading-normal " +
                  (openTab === 1
                    ? "text-white bg-gradient-to-br from-purple-500 to-indigo-500"
                    : "text-purple-500 bg-white")
                }
                onClick={(e) => {
                  e.preventDefault()
                  setOpenTab(1)
                }}
                data-toggle="tab"
                href="#link1"
                role="tablist"
              >
                <i className="fas fa-rocket text-base mr-1"></i> In-Progress Projects
              </a>
            </li>
            <li className="-mb-px last:mr-0 flex-auto text-center">
              <a
                className={
                  "text-xs font-bold uppercase px-5 py-3 shadow-lg rounded block leading-normal " +
                  (openTab === 2
                    ? "text-white bg-gradient-to-br from-purple-500 to-indigo-500"
                    : "text-purple-500 bg-white")
                }
                onClick={(e) => {
                  e.preventDefault()
                  setOpenTab(2)
                }}
                data-toggle="tab"
                href="#link2"
                role="tablist"
              >
                <i className="fas fa-briefcase text-base mr-1"></i> Completed Projects
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <div className="relative flex flex-col min-w-0 break-words w-full mb-6 shadow-lg rounded">
            <div className="px-4 py-5 flex-auto">
              <div className="tab-content tab-space">
                <div className={openTab === 1 ? "block" : "hidden"} id="link1">
                  <div className="grid sm:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-3 gap-5 justify-items-center items-center">
                    {docs.length
                      ? docs.map((challenge) => {
                          return (
                            <ChallengeCard
                              key={challenge.id}
                              challenge={challenge}
                              btnTitle="Submit Solution"
                            />
                          )
                        })
                      : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6].map((n) => <SkeletonCard key={n} />)}
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div className={openTab === 2 ? "block" : "hidden"} id="link2">
                  <div className="grid sm:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-3 gap-5 justify-items-center">
                    {docs.length
                      ? docs.map((solution) => {
                          return <SolutionSummary key={solution.id} solution={solution} />
                        })
                      : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6].map((n) => <SkeletonCard key={n} />)}
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}

export default Tabs
```

Answer (score 1):

you have 3 stages, In 3 stages **When data is fetched but it's an empty array**
then check the variable(docs) length and if it is 0 then it's an empty array
in React you can do like this

```
{!docs.length && (<div>no solution found</div>)}
```

so the above code check if **docs.length** if 0 then it will be true and  no solution found will be shown.

Comment: I have only two stages in my code(loading state and after loading state). I think I didn't frame the question properly.

Comment: yeah, so after loading state, you need to check the condition